# как передать пароль из nodejs в bash скрипт?

Tags: node.js, bash, ssh, ssh-key

нужно через *nodejs* залогинить ключи *ssh*

я вызываю скрипт *bash*

**testObject.js**

```
let exec_command = await `bash TEST.sh ${HOST}`

const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(exec_command);

return stdout.trim()
```

дальше есть 2 преграды

1. вопрос (*can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is*)
   на который я должен ответить ***yes***
2. передать пароль

такое в случае с ssh-copy-id не сработало

```
sshpass -p your_password ssh-copy-id  root@${DO_IP}
```

по этому я пишу *echo  yes* но это тоже не сработало

**TEST.sh**

```
IP=$(nslookup  ${1} | awk -F': ' 'NR==6 { print $2 } ')
echo $(echo  yes | ssh-copy-id  root@${IP})
```

какие есть варианты это реализовать ?

если это можно реализовать на чистом *nodejs* то тоже подходит

Comment: Попробуй использовать [nssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nssh/v/1.2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал взаимодействие с интерактивной консольной программой через Expect.
Что-то типа такого:
https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/19_ssh_telnet/pexpect.html
Возможно и для ноды есть такое.

Другой вариант: поднять веб сервис, по ssh не ходить.
Или поднять веб сервис там, где можно положить ключ без пароля.